# How to automate a report from Stored SQL procedure in Task scheduler of Server Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a stored SQL procedure for a report and I want to schedule this in Server Manager for weekely run. Can someone please guide me, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the privileges to do so, there should be a job management section in SQL Sever Agent.  In that, you can make an SQL command that calls your procedure, and schedule it to run when you want to.